# Azure AD Reply Url doesn't takes # for Angular Lazy load

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

**Environment**

- Angular 5
- Azure AD Authentication via Adal-Angular

**Configuration**

- Routes have Url Fragment (via servername/#/route)
- Azure AD has reply Url without the route (https://myserver/login) which matches my route structure
- Adal-Angular config has exact same route as AzureAD config

**Challenge**
Authentication attempt is a success, but the redirect attempt fails saying the reply url mismatch.

Dev Config as

```
redirectUri: 'https://localhost:4200/loginKey/'    // for dev
// redirectUri: 'https://myserver/loginKey/'        // for qa
```

[image]

Even though I am not mentioning the # anywhere in my routes explicitly, the dev environment is automatically considering it while routing as well as Azure redirect. Dev environment successfully authenticates and receives the token.

The QA environment also works with # based routing, but while doing a redirect, it fails to match the url. The url are verified to be exactly the same, even the casing. When I type the url without #, it results in 404. When I try to add # in the Azure redirect url, it doesn't allows me.

Any additional information (code/config) can be provided

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Im not sure whether you need help on preserving state or with your auth

Comment: Just want a URL configuration which allows me to get the token successfully

Comment: Okay, but then all you have to do is to ensure the specified redirectUri within your AAD application matches the redirectUri when invoking the endpoint (check the Browser Network pannel)

Comment: just checked my response. Azure is only returning me the base url "https://myserver/" stripping off the route after that. Not sure why

Comment: did you also checked the reply url you specified on the request?

Comment: Not sure why, but I removed the route from the end (the route was for Login) from the Azure app registration and now it's working fine.. !  Even though I was sending the url with route included..